# ERROR Message: Trying to get property of non-object in CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to get data from a certain table where the member id from a dropdown lis value is equal to the id from the other table. And i'm using jquery ajax also.

Here's my controller **transactions.php**

```
function getdataload(){

    $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('member'));
    echo $this->db->get('loading_service')->row()->member;

}
```

And here's is my **view.php**

```
<label for="member">Member</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="member" name="member" required onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
                <option selected="" value="">--select--</option>
                 <?php foreach ($members as $row): ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $row->mem_id; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($row->mem_fname.' '.$row->mem_lname) ?></option>
                 <?php endforeach ?>
       </select>

<p class="help-block text-danger" style="margin-left: 600px; margin-top: -450px; color: red;"><span id="select_member"> </span></p>

<script>
$('#member').on('change',function(){
    $.post('<?php echo base_url("transactions/getdataload")?>',
        {
            mem_id:$(this).val()
        }).done(function(res)
        {
        $('#select_member').text(res);
    });
});

</script>
```

Please help me with this guys:

Comment: write your controller in to model means write getdataload() in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is make sure you are getting results from your query. Try something like

```
$query = $this->db->get(...);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return json_encode($query->result());
} else {
    return "No data found";
}
```

then handle the no data error gracefully in your ajax success code. I sort of guessed that you would want your query result returned as json.

Comment: i really don't have an idea sir to do this. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:
*model*

```
function getData()
{
        $this->db->select('field_name');
        $this->db->from('loading_service');
        $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('member'));
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
}
```

*Controller*

```
function getdataload(){

    $data['member'] = $this->model_name->getData();
    $this->load->view("view_name",$data);

}
```

Comment: Instead: $this->db->where('member',$this->input->post('mem_id')); (he posts with name 'mem_id' not 'member')